# close menu div on menu click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu which adds menuclose class to X to close menu.

This works fine but I also need menu to close if they select menu link.

Reason is its a onepage site.

I have tried a few bits of javascript with no success.

```
<div class="menubar">
    <a href="#nav" class="menu-reveal menuclose" style="right: 0px; left: auto; text-align: center; text-indent: 0px; font-size: 18px;">X</a>
    <nav class="menu-nav">
        <div>
            <ul style="width: 761px; display: block; overflow: hidden;">
              <li><a href="#Home" title="">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#About-Us" title="">About Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#Services" title="">Services</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> 
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: create a fiddle for the same

Comment: just create a function close(){} and call it when you click a link or close button :)

Comment: can you provide an example please?

Comment: It would make more sense to use `addClass()` and add something like `menu-open`, since the starting state of the menu should be closed. And of course remove that class when clicking on a link or the X.

Comment: the above shows classes when menu open.  menuclose is removed on X click

Answer (score 0):

Just Pass the menuclose class to X on click of a link...

```
$('.menu-nav li a').click(function(){
$('#nav').addClass('menuclose ')
})

})
```

Comment: $('.menu-nav li a').click(function(){
$('#nav').removeClass('menuclose')
})
any ideas

Comment: its addClass , not removeClass

Comment: the above shows menu open.  I need to close it.  Should I not remove the menuclose class to close?